# How to install Windows 10 Home 19018 update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, docker, windows-insider

I'm using windows home edition, I have the latest update installed 1909.

I want to install docker for windows 10 home edition. It keeps saying

`Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise (15063+) or Windows 10 Home (19018+).`

Should I join Windows insider? How long should I wait for that update to be released if I don't want to join windows insider?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Should I join the Windows Insider?

Windows 10 version 2004 (build 19041) was released on May 27th 2020.

> How long should I wait for that update to be released if I don't want to join windows insider?

As of May 27th 2020, you are not required to join the Insider Preview program, in order to receive a WSL2 compatible build (19041 or newer).

As of August 20th 2020, 18362.1049+ (1903) and 18363.1049+ (1909), both 1903 and 1909 both support WSL2.  **KB4566116 was released on August 20th 2020.**  Due to this patch it is now possible to run Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Home if you are not actually running Windows 10 version 2004 provided your minor build is greater than 1049.

> Last year we announced that Docker had released a preview of Docker Desktop with WSL 2 integration. We are now pleased to announce that we have completed the work to enable experimental support for Windows Home WSL 2 integration. This means that Windows Insider users in 19040 or higher can now install and use Docker Desktop!
>
> To get started with WSL 2 Docker Desktop on Windows home today you will need to be on **Windows Insider Preview build 19040** or higher and install the **Docker Desktop Edge 2.2.2.0**

Source: [Docker Desktop for Windows Home is here](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-desktop-for-windows-home-is-here/)

Answer (score 15):

Seems I had same problem, windows live update it saying everything is updated but from power shell if I run
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | % Buildnumber`,
I get `18363`.

so I've found this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

and by clicking to install now, I was able to install the may 2020 update

Comment: I tried the installer at that link and get a pop up error saying "Can't find the necessary file. Please check if your permission to write to the installation folder."

Comment: run it as administrator and check if your account has the right permission to install it

Comment: This answer helped me. Before update on running `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | % Buildnumber` I got: `18363`. And, after the update I'm getting `19041`.

Comment: @NatherWebber I did and that error was what I got.

Comment: it means you don't have the right to run that installer, I suppose

Comment: Excellent !! It worked for me also. Is this a pre-release version? Why Win Updater did not install it automatically?

Comment: I suppose because it is something that want to prevent to being installed from standard users? I don't know

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wait till late May, you can follow this **workaround** to enable Hyper-V and Containers in Windows 10 Home Edition: https://itnext.io/install-docker-on-windows-10-home-d8e621997c1d

> Currently to update to Windows 10, version 2004
>   (Build 19041), you will need to join the Windows
>   Insider program and select the "Release Preview" ring. The public
>   release should arrive by **late May**.
>
> From: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Please do not downvote answers without providing a comment explaining why

Answer (score -1):

**Successful Docker installation on Win 10 home edition, without joining Windows Insider (9/23/2020)**

**Initial conditions:** MSI laptop with intel core i5 9th gen processor, Win10 home came pre-installed. Initial Docker install attempt prompted that I needed build version 19041+, then aborted. Pre installed version was 1903. Note version is not the same as build version, but the two are related and can be cross referenced. Key takeaway is that Win 10 version 1903 has build version < 19041.

**Steps to resolve:**

1. Follow the [official Docker instructions for Win10 home](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install-windows-home/). (Install WSL 2 at minimum). Reboot when prompted.
2. [Follow this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (provided by [Makkou](https://superuser.com/users/1177952/makkou)) to get Win10 version 2004. This works without joining the Windows Insider program. Reboot when prompted.

**Notes:**
I did not need to change hyper V or any bios settings at all. Right-click PowerShell --> run as admin, and following the instructions verbatim was sufficient.

**Current Status:**

1. By running command winver, see current build version is 19041+ as shown below.
   [verify build version is 19041.508](https://i.stack.imgur.com/427SJ.png)
2. Verified installation by running Docker tutorial, successful run shown below.
   [verify successful clone, build, run of Docker tutorial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RaKi.png)